# verbatim environment does not produce monospace

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

I use quite a lot packages in my document and I cannot find which one's fault is that verbatim does not produce monospaces. Anyway, if I knew this, I have no idea how to solve problems when packages are not friendly to each other, so is there any solution with so little information?

Edited:
I just tried to look how does verbatim reacts to other packages I use, and font differently changed almost with every new package, however, it looked (more or less) not so bad. So the problem is because of language I use, what probably makes my problem more difficult to solve for those, who doesn't use these.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
for i=0:10
    y(find(x < 0 & x > 1)) = 10;
end;
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Edited with new relevant situation:
lithuanian caused one more font problem. I cannot get Times font with `\usepackage{pslatex}`, how to fix this?

Comment: Please try and boil (a copy of) your document down to a minimum demonstrating the problem. That is, remove all content but e.g. a verbatim environment, and then remove packages one by one until you find the package or combination of packages that causes the problem. Producing such a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is helpful both for you (in finding the error) and for those trying to help (we get info, and don't have to create examples of our own).

Comment: `pslatex` is an obsolete package. With `\usepackage{tgtermes}` you should get a Times clone that works with the Lithuanian encoding `L7x`. However this should be a different question, as the two problems are unrelated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that the "Lithuanian package" invoked by the `L7x` option doesn't set correctly the default typewriter type family: the following way to set up the document should work.

```
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
```

Comment: @myname Try contacting Sigitas Tolušis about this; the contact can be found at http://www.vtex.lt/tex/littex/

Comment: @myname: Please accept this answer then by clicking at the tick symbol below the voting arrows. Also check your other questions.